# Python ImageDraw как можно "центрировать" текст?

Tags: python

Не совсем уверен, что слово "центрировать" здесь уместно, но постараюсь объяснить.

Я генерирую изображение с текстом при помощи ImageDraw как-то так:

```
draw.text((431, 315), i[1], fill=color, font=font)
draw.text((431, 515), i[1], fill=color, font=font)
```

Например получилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде все правильно, текст там где нужен, но если я его сделаю длиннее, то он начинает уходить в бок...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтобы он расширялся в стороны, как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за объяснение того как это называется или примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Простого решения нету. Есть параметр центровки многострочного текста в пределах текстбокса, но это не то, что вам нужно. С другой стороны, совсем не сложно написать пару строк кода, чтобы решить эту проблему:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

width = 200
height = 200

def centertext(text:str, ypos:int): #второй аргумент - положение текста по вертикали
#  то есть расстояние от верхней границы холста до верхней границы текстбокса
    txtwidth = draw.textsize(text, font=fnt)[0]
    draw.text(((width-txtwidth)/2,ypos), text, fill="red",font=fnt)

img = Image.new("RGBA",(width,height))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.ellipse((60, 60, 140, 140), outline ='black')
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('verdana.ttf', 20)

centertext("Stackoverflow", 30)

img.save("centered.png", "PNG")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Параметры `(431, 315)` и `(431, 515)` в вашем коде - это [верхний левый угол текста](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text). Поэтому вам нужно

- рассчитать длину выводимого текста, и
- соответствующим образом изменить этот параметр.

Comment: Это случайные координаты, я просто написал для примера. Неужели нету простого способа чтобы текст расширялся в бока? (В фотошопе это называется выключка например и делается одним нажатием)